# JRE version must be equal to or above JDK version?

Tags: java, compilation, jvm, bytecode, backwards-compatibility

I've read that the bytecodes that the JDK generate are generic. What I say is that they only do things like memory mapping, calling, etc... So if that's true, it would mean that I can, for example, if write a program with characteristics of JDK 1.7, I don't need to worry about if it can run in a user with JRE 1.6? (It's an example, it could happen with more exagerated cases).

So, my question is: Can I write a program with new things from 1.7 and run it in 1.6?

Comment: No. The byte code or class has a version which restricts them.  This means that Java 6 can't read/execute Java 7 compiled classes. This prevents issues where a feature in Java 7 simply isn't available in Java 6 and below.  You can use Java 7 to generate "compatible" classes for Java 6, but this will eliminate the possibility of using Java 7 features within the code

Comment: What specific 'new things' were of interest to you?

Comment: There are many, for example NIO2...

Comment: *"I've read that the bytecodes that the JDK generate are generic."* I don't think you understand what that means, or, never read anything from where you read that ever again.

Comment: @MadProgrammer at least not without some ugly hacks

Comment: @Antimony "Ugly Hacks" make no guarantee of working results

Comment: I'm just saying you could do it if you really want to. Probably not a good idea except for personal use though.

Comment: read about java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can I write a program with new things from 1.7 and run it in 1.6?

No.  Java is not backward compatible.

Note that it is possible to create code compatible with a Java 1.6 JRE in a 1.7 JDK by using the [cross-compilation options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-options), but that code can only use the classes, attributes, methods and language features available in version 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I write a program with new things from 1.7 and run it in 1.6?

The short answer is yes, but it is not officially supported. You'll have to resort to some hacks, but you can get it to work if you really want to. I wouldn't recommend doing this in a major project though.

In general bytecode is not backwards compatible because each classfile contains a version field. The JVM will refuse to run classes with a higher version than it was built for (lower versions are of course ok). By default, the javac that comes with Java 7 will create classes with version 51.0, which means they can only be executed by the JVM that comes with Java 7 or higher.

However, this doesn't mean it's impossible if you really want to create Java 6 compatible code. You can tell the compiler to generate classfiles with an earlier version. All this means is that you won't be able to use library and bytecode level features introduced in the new version.

Luckily, version 51.0 did not actually introduce any new bytecode features used by javac. All of the new features in Java 7 are implemented at compile time - the bytecode isn't any different except for the version! This means that any Java 7 class can be made to work as long as it doesn't rely on standard library updates (for example Try With Resources requires library support).

Unfortunately, javac refuses to compile Java 7 to version 50.0. But you can always change the bytecode version field yourself, either manually or with a tool. Since there were no new bytecode features, it will work just fine.

P.S. Memory mapping is down by the VM. There's no bytecode instructions for it. But you have the right idea.

Comment: "Luckily, version 51.0 did not actually introduce any new bytecode features used by Java.". This is completely incorrect. Actually, the entire answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Brian which new features do you believe it added? Because invokedynamic is not used by Java.

Comment: Don't care. The statement is still false. Beyond  that, rather that telling someone there's no difference and obviously it was done for "unknown reasons" and they could possibly hack the binary files and maybe they'd work with an 8 year old version of the JVM that has been EoL'd by Oracle ... how about we stick with the practical and real-world answer which is, no.

Comment: @Brian I'm confused. If you don't know and don't care about the answer, how are you so certain that I'm incorrect? Anyway, the practical and real world answer is that you can make this work if you really want to, but it's not officially supported and requires some binary hacking.

Comment: If I'm wrong, I'd love to hear why so I can learn something new. But simply claiming I'm wrong without providing any evidence or explaining what you think is wrong is not helpful.

Comment: It might be more correct to say that *javac* does not use of `INVOKEDYNAMIC` rather then "Java". I also want to add that some byte code frameworks intentionally reduce the version of classes in order to make the classes pass the verifier which does not check stack maps for version 50 classes. There are use cases so to say.

Comment: @Raphw True. I'll change that to clarify it. It's theoretically possible that an alternate Java compiler could generate invokedynamics.

Comment: That's not surprising, since it was intended for non-Java languages on the JVM (though it will probably be used for lambdas too once Java 8 comes out).